# Android Nested Scrollview

Tags: android

I have this nested scroll view in which i have taken a recycler view in my xml.

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#eaeaea"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="13dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvcategories"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"

                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

But it takes only 3 items in a row on the screen with scroll.I want is it takes as many items as there are in the list on the screen displayed to the user.
I just want is the whole screen should screen with all the list items to be present on the screen without scrolling.

Comment: I don't understand "I just want is the whole screen should screen with all the list items to be present on the screen without scrolling,,"

Comment: You can go with Sectioned ListView which can have multiple View types as per your requirement. And if you want to adjust your view according to screen size then give size of your items depend on the screen size.

Comment: can you add the diagrammatic representation of view you are trying to create

Comment: @gopal,Ijust want the exact layout as in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
    <TextView/>
    .
    .
    .    
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Use LinearLayout to add multiple items. ScrollView won't affect the dimensions of the Views inside. You can add as many views as you need without worrying about screen size or View size.